# How to iterate through a table row and perform a specific operation at a <td> if an element exists is true?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following table here:

```html
<table id="users-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="uid">1234</td>
    <td class="user-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

There are multiple `<tr>` in the `<tbody>`

I need to write code to check if the `.uid` class of `<td>` matches the `uID` variable in the code and if it does, I need to check that checkbox with the class `.user-checkbox`.

Comment: Which part are you having an issue with?  The selection or the iteration?  Also, do you have control over the html if alterations to it would make the logic easier?

Comment: I'm confused how to iterate through the table. And yes, I can make some alterations to html but not change the structure of table itself.

Comment: Ok, so what I would suggest is that you change the td into a form of: `<td class="uid" data-uid="1234">1234</td>`.  This would allow you to perform a selector of `$('#users-table td[data-uid="whatevervalue"]')` to find the element with a matching uid.

Comment: However, to iterate through the table would simply be `$('#users-table td.uid'').each(function(){ ... });`

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. If you have the `uID` in a variable, select the `td` which contains that text directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a native JS code

```js
const uID = 1234;

const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#users-table tbody tr");
rows.forEach(row => {
  const uidCell = row.querySelector(".uid");
  if (uidCell.textContent === uID.toString()) {
    const checkbox = row.querySelector(".user-checkbox input");
    checkbox.checked = true;
  }
});
```